# How does alzheimer's affect an octopus, particularly relating to their multiple brains?

Tags: pathology

From what I have read, Octopus' have multiple brains rather than a single one like in humans. They are also affected by alzheimer's, and so an interesting question arises:

Do Octopus' get alzheimer's in one brain, or are all affected, and can they shut off a single brain if it gets the disease?

Comment: I have no idea. Was hoping someone knowledgable could give a full rundown but if not will have to research this sort of thing :-)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is an interesting question. Could you please add a reference about Alzheimer's in Octopus?

Comment: Pathology due to Alzheimer's disease is primarily because of the loss of neurons which cannot be repaired. Many organisms can actually regenerate their brains because they have active adult neurogenesis (which is reduced to a few small regions of brain in most mammals).